# Where can I find a detailed map of Frankfurt Airport?

Tags: maps, fra

My grandmother will be flying through Frankfurt Airport and would need to switch terminals, so I'd like to send her a map in advance. Unfortunately the official website only hosts a [simple schematic map](https://www.frankfurt-airport.com/en/flights---more/transfer.detail.suffix.html/article/flights-and-more/terminal-transfer/terminal-maps.html) which is a bit difficult to read.

Does a detailed map of the airport exist? I'm thinking of something like [Heathrow's official maps](http://www.heathrow.com/airport-guide/getting-around-heathrow/airport-maps).

Comment: Do you mean [one more like this](http://ontheworldmap.com/germany/city/frankfurt/frankfurt-airport-terminal-map.html) ?

Comment: I would like to only advise that I had multiple nervous issues 2 months ago with getting from Terminal 1 to 2 by feet. I finally found the "SKYLINE" train with really tiny signs, which brought me to Terminal 2 in about 5 Minutes. It leaves every 90 seconds, when it is not being repaired. But you first have to find it, which can be challenging when you're in the vast Terminal 1. Tell your grandmother to ask someone for "Skyline-Bahn" to the other Terminal, all service personnel should know that. (You probably mean Rhein-Main Airport near Frankfurt, Germany, where I am also living)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The one comparable to the Heathrow one you mentioned can be found here:

https://www.frankfurt-airport.com/en/flights---more/transfer.overview.map.html

Comment: Alas this page goes to 404 and wayback machine shows it was last accessible in 2017 and airports change enough that I wouldn't necessarily trust a five year old map. Is there an updated URL? I wonder whether https://www.frankfurt-airport.com/en/airport-guide/orientation/airport-map.html is it.

Answer (score 3):

Some of the terminals are mapped fairly well on [OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=18/50.04912/8.57076), which you can export as images (click the Share button on the right-hand side, then Download).

Answer (score 2):

I have never used myself but here is an app for navigation in airports including Frankfurt airport: [here is the link.](https://www.infsoft.com/industries/airports/success-story)

Though when I visited Frankfurt Airport and needed to change terminals, I did not find it particularly difficult.

Comment: Is this your app?

Comment: Come on, the app is a default way to get a map for a number of airports, why are you marking this as spam?